# C++ Overriding private class attributes

Tags: c++, class, attributes, overriding, reset

Anyone can advise on how to simply reset a class' private attributes? (referring to `int forward` and `int backwards` from within `Default` class)

What I want to achieve:

**Case 1:** Use `int forward` and `int backwards` with default values `VK_UP` and `VK_DOWN` << **This is done.**

**Case 2:** I want to be able to reset the default into some other keypress. << **ADVICE HERE needed**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>
#include<conio.h>

using namespace std;
bool reset_defaults = false;

class Replace_defaults {
public:
    void check() {
        switch (reset_defaults) {
        case true:
            cout << ("Now running with reset commands >>>\n");
            //// HERE override function ...
            break;
        }
    }
};

// Base class
class Default {
    int forward = VK_UP; // << **TO RESET!!**
    int backwards = VK_DOWN;
public:

    bool standBy = true;
    void get_default() {
        int new_def = forward;
    }
    int move() {
        while (reset_defaults == false) {
            if (GetAsyncKeyState(forward) < 0)
            {
                cout << ("FORWARDS >>>\n");
                if (GetAsyncKeyState(forward) == 0)
                {
                    cout << ("Stopped forwards\n");
                }
            }
            if (GetAsyncKeyState(backwards) < 0)
            {
                cout << ("BACKWARDS >>>\n");
                if (GetAsyncKeyState(backwards) == 0)
                {
                    cout << ("Stopped backwards\n");
                }
            }
            if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RIGHT) < 0)
            {
                reset_defaults = true;
                cout << ("RIGHT Key pressed - Stopped \n");
                Replace_defaults reset;
                reset.check();
            }
            if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_SPACE) < 0) { break; }
        }
        return 0;
    }
    int accessPrivate() {
        return forward;
    }
};
class Replace_defaults_overload: public Replace_defaults {
public:
    void check() {
        switch (reset_defaults) {
        case false:
            cout << "Default comands running \n";
            Default test;
            test.move();
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    Replace_defaults_overload replace;
    Default def;
    replace.check();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Having them under the protected access modifier would allow an inherited class to change the values of forward and backward. Otherwise private is only accessible within the parent class

```
    class Default {
protected
    int forward = VK_UP; // << **TO RESET!!**
    int backwards = VK_DOWN;
public: ...
```